# URL Rewrite: how to remove email parameters from an URL in Apache?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I remove email parameters from an URL on an Apache server using a rewrite rule?

Basically I need to strip out whatever email parameter is present in an url, so for example:

```
 www.example.com/?param_name=nobody@example.com
```

will be rewritten as

```
www.example.com/
```

or

```
 www.example.com/?param_name_1=not_an_email&param_name_2=nobody@example.com
```

to

```
 www.example.com/?param_name_1=not_an_email
```

Comment: What rule have you tried for this?

Comment: Problem is that I know how to remove a string from a url, for example: 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/stringtoremove/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

But I don't know how to detect if a part of the url is an email address and remove that parameter

Comment: What's the intent behind it? From where are you getting these URLs with email address?

Comment: I've received a "Violations of the Identifying Users Policy" from Google AdSense because someone is reaching the websites through external links that cointains an email parameter (probably to track referrals) so I want to strip them out automatically hoping that this will solve the issue with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+|)?&[^=]*=[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}((?:&(.*))|)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]*=[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule (.*) ? [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]*=[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(&|)((?:&(.*))|)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%3 [NC,L]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

The first rule matches query strings where there are other parameters both before and optionally after the email address, e.g:

```
www.example.com/?param_name_1=not_an_email&param_name_2=nobody@example.com
```

or

```
www.example.com/?param_name_1=not_an_email&param_name_2=nobody@example.com&param_name_3=not_an_email
```

The second rule matches query strings consisting of a single parameter which is an email address, e.g:

```
www.example.com/?param_name=nobody@example.com
```

The third rule matches query strings where the email adress is the first parameter and other parameters follow, e.g:

```
www.example.com/?param_name_1=nobody@example.com&param_name_2=not_an_email
```

It only matches one email address maximum. The regex for matching an email address is from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: I tried to apply these rules but they are not working. This is my current htaccess [link](http://pastebin.com/eWBkPW0T). All the other rules ("#no www" and "#pages") are working, but not the "#strip email" rules...

Comment: Try testing whatever URL strings you are using on that testing site I linked to just to verify whether it's a problem with the regex or some other site configuration issue

Comment: Ohn the testing site they are working properly with my htaccess. I don't know why they are not working on the server (shared hosting). So it's probably a misconfiguration?